# downloading data from the degree function in R

Tags: r, igraph

I use the ready function degree,
how to get vertices (results at the top)

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 7 10 6 9 12 15 14 11
```

the function returns me the result, and for the analysis I also need the bottom part

```
> measure1<-degree(g1)
    > measure1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  7 10  6  9 12 15 14 11 
     3  5  1  3  2  1  4  3  2  3  1  2  1  1
```

> ```
> g1 <-read.table(listcsv[k])
> g1 <- graph.data.frame(g1,directed=FALSE)
> ```

```
0 1
0 6
0 9
1 6
1 7
1 12
1 15
2 7
3 4
3 10
3 14
4 9
5 9
7 10
7 11
10 15
```

Comment: 1) When you use a function from a package start the code with `library(pkgname)`. 2) Post, **in the question**, minimal code that creates `g1`.

Comment: The question is not very clear. What is `g1`? Where from did you get the `degree` function?

Comment: edited in post,

Comment: @Kubazooo Where did you get function `degree` from? You should mention package name or share source code of function.

Comment: degree is a built-in function in R
I did not modify anything myself

Comment: data.frame(Vertex = V(g1), Degree = degree(g1))`. I hope this is it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas great, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Welcom to Stack Exchange & thanks for your question. However I recommend to you to read about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There will be higher probability to get an answer.

As of your question the `degree` function of `igraph` package returns a named vector, where names of vector values are vortices. Please see an example below:

```
library(igraph)
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda"),
                     age=c(48,33,45,34,21),
                     gender=c("F","M","F","M","F"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                        same.dept=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
                        friendship=c(4,5,5,2,1,1), advice=c(4,5,5,4,2,3))
g <- graph.data.frame(relations, directed=TRUE, vertices=actors)
r <- degree(g)

# extraction of degree(g) names (vortices)
d <- data.frame(degrees = degree(g), nms = names(r))
d
```

Output:

```
          degrees       nms
Alice           4     Alice
Bob             3       Bob
Cecil           2     Cecil
David           2     David
Esmeralda       1 Esmeralda
```